# Required is not working in <select required/>

Tags: html, required

```
 <div class="form-group">
<div class="controls">
<label class="required" asp-for="Designation"></label>                                                           <span class="danger" asp-validation-for="Designation"></span>
<select id="Designation" name="Designation" class="form-control" asp-for="Designation" required>
<option value="0" selected>Please select a Designation</option>
        @foreach (var item in designation list)
              {<option value="@item.DesignationName">@item.DesignationName</option>
                       }
   </select></div>
```

this is my html drop down where designation list fetch the data of all employee which works fine
MY PROBLEM is that the I put required in select statement for validation and  which doesn't work as it do not shows any message when field is not filled .How can I solve this

I need when No designation is selected it shows field required message on form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an empty value in the first  tag, since required works on empty elements. You may refer to the [documentation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/#the-select-element) if needed.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="required" asp-for="Designation"></label>
        <span class="danger" asp-validation-for="Designation"></span>
        <select id="Designation" name="Designation" class="form-control" asp-for="Designation" required>
            <option value="" selected>Please select a Designation</option>
                @foreach (var item in designation list)
                {
                    <option value="@item.DesignationName">@item.DesignationName</option>
                }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @NidhiAggarwal Welcome. Please do tick mark the answer as a working solution : )